# substr method on link text and add ellipses?

Tags: jquery, substr

```
$("a.newslinks").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().length > 38) {
            $(this).text().substr(35); //does not work
            $(this).append('...'); //works
            $(this).css({ "color" : "#ff00cc" }); //works
        }
    });
```

If a link has its text longer than 38 characters, how can I trim it to 35 chars and add an elipses at the end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`substr(35)` will *chop* 35 characters off the start of the string - not limit it to 35 chars in length.

Try:

```
.substr(0, 35)
```

Also, this function just returns a new string - it doesn't change the original. So you need to do

```
$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 35));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 35));
```